# Wondering how to show the role added within a command inside of an embed

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to define the role added and add it into an embed.
Like, the role added within that command

Looked on google, nothing, Looked on here and the same result.

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}warn`){
var role1 = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Warning 1");
var role1 = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Warning 2");
  var role1 = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Warning 3");        
  if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Staff"].includes(r.name)) )
  return message.reply("ERROR | You do not have sufficient permissions to 
  do this command.");
  if(!member)
  return message.reply("ERROR | Unable to find the user you mentioned.");
  if(!reason)
  return message.reply("ERROR | To use this command, you need to specify 
  a reason.");  
  if rUser.roles.some(r=>["Warning 3"].includes(r.name))
    return rUser.kick       
  if rUser.roles.some(r=>["Warning 2"].includes(r.name))
    return rUser.addRole(role3)   
  if rUser.roles.some(r=>["Warning 1"].includes(r.name))
    return rUser.addRole(role2)             
  if (!rUser.roles.some(r=>["Warning 1"].includes(r.name)) )
    return rUser.addRole(role1)        
await message.channel.send("Command processed. (WARN)")  
 let warnEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
 .setColor("#FFD700")
 .setDescription("Warn")
 .addField("Warned User", `${member}`)
 .addField("Warned By", `${message.author}`)
 .addField("Reason", `${reason}`); 
 .addField("Warning issued", `${}`)   
 let sendchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "action-log");
 return sendchannel.send(warnEmbed);
```

Right at the bottom where it says "Warning issued" I want it to show the role added at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a return of a embed on each if

```js
 if (cmd === `${prefix}warn`) {
    var role1 = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Warning 1");
    var role2 = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Warning 2");
    var role3 = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Warning 3");
    if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["Staff"].includes(r.name)))
        return message.reply("ERROR | You do not have sufficient permissions to do this command.");
    if (!member)
        return message.reply("ERROR | Unable to find the user you mentioned.");
    if (!reason)
        return message.reply("ERROR | To use this command, you need to specify a reason.");
    let sendchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "action-log");
    if (rUser.roles.some(r => ["Warning 2"].includes(r.name))) {
        let warnEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("#FFD700")
            .setDescription("Warn")
            .addField("Warned User", `${member}`)
            .addField("Warned By", `${message.author}`)
            .addField("Reason", `${reason}`)
            .addField("Warning issued", `${role3}`)
        await rUser.addRole(role3)
        return sendchannel.send(warnEmbed);
    }
    if (rUser.roles.some(r => ["Warning 1"].includes(r.name))) {
        let warnEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("#FFD700")
            .setDescription("Warn")
            .addField("Warned User", `${member}`)
            .addField("Warned By", `${message.author}`)
            .addField("Reason", `${reason}`)
            .addField("Warning issued", `${role2}`)
        await rUser.addRole(role2)
        return sendchannel.send(warnEmbed);
    }
    if (!rUser.roles.some(r => ["Warning 1"].includes(r.name))) {
        let warnEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("#FFD700")
            .setDescription("Warn")
            .addField("Warned User", `${member}`)
            .addField("Warned By", `${message.author}`)
            .addField("Reason", `${reason}`)
            .addField("Warning issued", `${role1}`)
        await rUser.addRole(role1)
        return sendchannel.send(warnEmbed);
    }
}
```

Comment: so the entire thing should look something like this? https://pastebin.com/VeD8drn4 Keeps saying "unexpected identifier" for member. (rUser was from another command but forgot to change)

Comment: Nevermind, You messed some ";"'s up and some other little bits but thanks!

Comment: Yeah i was doing it from the phone my sorrys